# Bootstrap Modal is not working with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

This modal is not popping up at all.the modal should pop up on a failed login attempt.
I have uploaded the design and code behind code for reference.

this is design page code.

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>SFPL's AMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/form-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() {
        $("#btnShowPopup").click();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="top-content">
        <div class="inner-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                        <h1><strong>पदोन्नति</strong></h1>
                        <div class="description">
                             <p>
                                 Login Form Pre-Design Phase Starts Here.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>xxxxxxx</h3>
                                <p>Enter your username and password to log on:</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="login-form" runat="server">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter User ID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group"> 
                                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-key"></span></span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Login" 
                                       runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" Style="width: 100%"> </asp:Button>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lblLoginSuccess" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  

                                </div>                         
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnShowPopup" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        Launch demo modal
                    </button>          
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                                        Registration done Successfully</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                        Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I copied this code from the the 
web(https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/111893/Open-Show-BootStrap-Modal-Popup-from-Server-Side-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet/)

, this works perfectly fine in a new web-application but its not working here at all.
Please let me know what i am missing
 what's running from behind is:

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Cls_BA_FieldStaffEO user = new Cls_BA_FieldStaffEO();
     user.LoadFieldStaffbyUserAccountName(txtUserName.Text);
     lblLoginSuccess.CssClass = "error";
     lblLoginSuccess.Text = "";
     string password;

     if (txtPassword.Text != "" && user.Password != null)
     {
            password = Cls_StringHelpers.Decrypt(user.Password.Trim());
            //BEGIN: Fix for Bug ID -18020
            if (txtPassword.Text == password && user.IsActive == true)
            {
                //END: Fix for Bug ID - 18020
                Session["Roles"] = (Cls_MA_RoleEOList)ViewState["Roles"];
                Session["UserID"] = user.ID;
                Session["UserName"] = user.UserAccountName;
                Session["BaseRegionID"] = user.RegionID;
                Session["BaseRegionName"] = user.RegionName;
                Session["BaseDistrictID"] = user.DistrictID;
                Session["BaseDistrictName"] = user.DistrictName;
                Session["BaseBranchID"] = user.BranchID;
                Session["BaseBranchName"] = user.BranchName;
                Session["BaseUnitID"] = user.UnitID;
                Session["BaseUnitName"] = user.UnitName;
            //Session["Ver"] = trigger.InnerText.Trim();
            //Session["VerToolTip"] =Convert.ToString(ViewState["VerToolTip"]); 
                if (user.CheckDuplicateLogUser(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"])))
                {

                //lblMsg.CssClass = "error";
                Cls_MA_ListLoginUserResultBOList LoginDetails = new Cls_MA_ListLoginUserResultBOList();
                LoginDetails.List(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));
                Session["UnitID"] = LoginDetails[0].UnitId;
                //lblLoginSuccess.CssClass = "text-danger";
                //lblLoginSuccess.Text = "<b>Please Logout As You Are ALREADY LOGGED IN </b> From <b>" + LoginDetails[0].UnitName.Trim() + "</b> Unit.<br/>Or<br />The <b>Browser Was Closed</b> Forcefully.";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
                this.lblMessage.Text = "Your Registration is done successfully. Our team will contact you shotly";
            }
                else
                {

                    Response.Redirect("~/Common/f_CN_OuterHome.aspx");
                }

            }
            else
            {
            //lblLoginSuccess.Text = (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Master_ErrorMessages", "regLoginSuccess");
            //lblLoginSuccess.CssClass = "text-danger";
            //ClearControls();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
            this.lblMessage.Text = "Your Registration is done successfully. Our team will contact you shotly";
        }
        }
        else
        {
        //lblLoginSuccess.Text = (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Master_ErrorMessages", "regLoginSuccess");
        //lblLoginSuccess.CssClass = "text-danger";
        //ClearControls();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
        this.lblMessage.Text = "Your Registration is done successfully. Our team will contact you shotly";
    }

}
```

Comment: Too much code.  Debug and be more specific about what specifically is happening vs. what specifically you're expecting to happen.  What is your modal?  Why are you expecting it to display?  Are you refreshing the entire page and thereby losing any JavaScript context entirely?  Something else?  Be specific.

Comment: Can you open it manually? Do you have any console errors on your browser?

Comment: there are no errors what so ever..its just that the modal pop up is not opening !